# bat file don't work next line commands

Tags: windows, batch-file, cmd

i need set the IP and Default gateway for my internet connection by bat file.
in CMD.exe run as Administrator my command worked as well but i create bat file and write my Command like this

```
@Echo off
netsh
interface ip set address name="Local Area Connection" static 192.168.10.42 255.255.255.0 192.168.1.1
```

but if i run the bat file it wait at first line

```
netsh>
```

please help me to find out: Why my bat file dose not work.(sorry for my bad English)

Comment: Why do you put the arguments on the next line then?

Comment: All the options for the NETSH command have to be on the same line as NETSH.

Comment: thank you for helping
` netsh interface ip set address name="Local Area Connection" stat
ic 192.168.10.42 255.255.255.0 192.168.1.1 `

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The bat file must be run as Administrator to set IP address.